# How to check target view in `onInterceptTouchEvent`

Tags: java, android

I have a conundrum. I'm writing a game in Android, and at the start of every game I display a "tip." The tip is a box with some text and a little "x" button to close it. But I don't want players to have to click the x button, so I made it so the entire gameboard intercepts click events and closes the tip box on the first click.

To do that, I overrode the `onInterceptTouchEvent` method in the `RelativeLayout` the gameboard sits in to call the method to close the tip box, and then allow the click event to filter down to whatever child was being clicked.

My issue is that that's OK everywhere except where the "X" button for the tip box is. The restart button just so happens to be below that "X" button. And so if you try to click the "X" button to close the tip, the RelativeLayout sees the click event, calls the method to close the tip box, and because the "X" button is no longer there, the restart button ends up being clicked (which in a deliciously ironic way restarts the game and brings up another tip!).

I can't figure out a clean, pleasant way to fix this.

Here's my onIntercept method:

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    if (closeBubbleOnNextClick) {
        gameboardActivity.onCloseSpeechBubble(null);
        closeBubbleOnNextClick = false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I can't get the target view out of `MotionEvent` to not close the tip if the tip's "X" button is the target. I don't really want to disable the reset button in that method, because depending on the device size, the "X" button may be over a different button entirely (like the home button), and I don't see a good way to create a call back to turn it back on anyway.

I don't want to do something hokey like running the method to close the tip button delayed on a separate thread, because it would either cause a weird delay in when the tip box disappears, or be prone to failure depending on the device performance.

Does anyone know a clean way to close the tip box on any click *except* a click that would be on the tip box's "X" button?

Here is the tip box. It is just a `FrameLayout` with a few views inside it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/speech_bubble_wrapper"
    style="@style/TutorialBubble"
    android:padding="@dimen/default_margin"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <!--
    Ideally, the x button's touch box should be increased in size
    whenever this view is inflated
    -->

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/speech_bubble_image"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/speech_bubble_width"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/speech_bubble" />

    <com.ponyseeker.models.ui.PonyTextView
        android:id="@+id/speech_bubble_text"
        style="@style/PonyFontBody"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/speech_bubble_width"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="@dimen/speech_bubble_text_margin"
        android:textSize="@dimen/speech_bubble_text_size" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/speech_bubble_x"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/speech_bubble_x_width"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top|right"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:onClick="onCloseSpeechBubble"
        android:src="@drawable/speech_bubble_x" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Maybe I could check the absolute location of the click, and compare that with the "X" button's click box to see if they match?

Comment: What exactly is the tip bubble? Is it a view? Is it a PopupWindow?

Comment: @Karakuri Added the code for it. It's just a normal `FrameLayout` view.

Comment: You might consider looking at PopupWindow, since that can be dismissed by a touch outside its window and you likely wouldn't need to do any touch event hackery.

Comment: Do you know if it is possible and reasonable to completely define the appearance of a popupWindow, and set its location in a relative layout? [The docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html) make it sound like it's more like a dialog box than what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I think setContentView on the PopupWindow should allow you to provide any appearance you want. As for positioning it in a `RelativeLayout`,  that I don't know. You might have to do something to figure out the X and Y coordinates at which to show it instead.